# Need to extract part of string using shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, cut

I have a script like,

```
#/bin/bash -x
LASTBUILD=' 174254491  2018-08-08T11:04:40Z  gs://abc/kishor/5.4.0.61/xyz-5.4.0-61.tgz
 TOTAL: 46 objects, 7325896651 bytes (6.82 GiB)'

echo "this is the LASTBUILD ============== $LASTBUILD"

LATESTBUILD=echo $LASTBUILD | cut -d ' ' -f 3

echo "this is the LATESTBUILD ############### $LATESTBUILD"
```

After execution shows result as below,

```
[root@root ~]# echo $LATESTBUILD

[root@root ~]#
```

My expected result is as below,

```
[root@root ~]# echo $LATESTBUILD
gs://abc/kishor/5.4.0.61/xyz-5.4.0-61.tgz
[root@root ~]#
```

The above code is not working.

PS:
Also tried using awk but not worked,

```
LATESTBUILD=$LASTBUILD | awk -F '/' '{print $5}'
```

Comment: What output do you get from your script? I can already see that you're failing to use `export` so any variable set inside the script are not going to be recognized by the shell after the script exits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your script:

1. Your hash bang is invalid.  You have `#/bin/bash -x` and it should be `#!/bin/bash -x`
2. Your LASTBUILD variable is weird.  Each column is separated by double spaces which will cause `cut` to act oddly, and you also don't want a newline in it with cut.
3. `LATESTBUILD=echo $LASTBUILD | cut -d ' ' -f 3` is nothing.  This should be in [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), but even then it wont work because of the double spacing.  It should be: `LATESTBUILD=$(cut -d ' ' -f5 <<<"$LASTBUILD")`
4. The variables set inside your script will not be available outside of it, so doing `echo $LATESTBIULD` on the command line after the script executes will not and should not work.

Here is a working version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LASTBUILD='174254491   2018-08-08T11:04:40Z  gs://abc/kishor/5.4.0.61/xyz-5.4.0-61.tgz TOTAL: 46 objects, 7325896651 bytes (6.82 GiB)'

echo "this is the LASTBUILD ============== $LASTBUILD"

LATESTBUILD=$(cut -d ' ' -f5 <<<"$LASTBUILD")

echo "this is the LATESTBUILD ############### $LATESTBUILD"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ print $3 }' <<< $LASTBUILD
```

The default field separator in awk in a space and so print the 3rd space delimited field.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it (carefully) with the shell:

```
LASTBUILD=' 174254491  2018-08-08T11:04:40Z  gs://abc/kishor/5.4.0.61/xyz-5.4.0-61.tgz TOTAL: 46 objects, 7325896651 bytes (6.82 GiB)'
set -f               # disable filename generation (globbing)
set -- $LASTBUILD    # specifically un-quoted, to allow splitting
LATESTBUILD=$3
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
read _ _ LATESTBUILD _ <<< $LASTBUILD
```

Comment: you'd also want to disable filename generation with `set -f`, just in case there were any wildcards in the contents of the variable.